# NSArrayM tableView]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

I have two days trapped  because  do not work my NSArray.

when I run the application  everything works well  but when I touch searchBar  the application is closed  reason: '- [__NSArrayM tableView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e34c50'

```
@implementation ViewController


-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
return YES;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
[super viewDidLoad];

monthArray = [[ NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Paliwizumab",@"Opis przedmiotu zamówienia",@"Paliwizumab a 0,1g inj I.M ( proszek + rozpuszczalnik)",@"Paliwizumab a 0,05 g I.M ( proszek + rozpuszczalnik )",@"Nazwa międzynarodowa",@"PALIVISUMABUM*",@"Paliwizumab01",@"Paliwizumab02",@"Paliwizumab03",@"Paliwizumab04",@"Paliwizumab05",@"Paliwizumab06", nil];


[searchBar setParentController:self];
[searchBar setParentController:monthArray];
[searchBar setDelegate:searchBar];


[self prefersStatusBarHidden];

}
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:searchBar selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:          (UIKeyboardWillShowNotification ) object:nil];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated

[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:searchBar];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [[self monthArray]count];

}   


-(NSMutableArray*)monthArray
{
if (searchBar.isSearching == 1)
    return  searchBar.searchArray;

else
    return  monthArray;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellId = @"CellId";
UITableViewCell *cell = [self->_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellId];
if (! cell)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellId];
[cell.textLabel setText:[[self monthArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath. row]];
return cell;

}



@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "JPSearchBar.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate>

 {
NSMutableArray       *monthArray;
IBOutlet JPSearchBar *searchBar;
}


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

-(NSMutableArray*)monthArray;


@end
```

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and it might show you precisely where you are accidentally calling the `tableView` method on a `NSMutableArray` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Objective-C, the "unrecognized selector" error means that you tried to execute a method on an object (i.e. "send it a message" where the "message" is identified by a "selector"), but the object doesn't implement that method (i.e. "doesn't recognize that selector").

This often happens when you have an object of the wrong class. In this case I'm guessing that the `setParentController:` method of your `searchBar` expects some object that implements `tableView` (maybe `self` because I see it has a `tableView` property which means it has a `tableView` getter method) but you give it `monthArray` instead. This is just a guess though, because the rest of your code is missing. (E.g. what's `JPSearchBar`?)

Comment: Thanks TaylanUB  I have two days struggling with this give it monthArray instead is this